# Scrapy crawl blocked with 403/503

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm running Scrapy 0.24.4, and have encountered quite a few sites that shut down the crawl very quickly, typically within 5 requests. The sites return 403 or 503 for every request, and Scrapy gives up. I'm running through a pool of 100 proxies, with the `RotateUserAgentMiddleware` enabled.

Does anybody know how a site could identify Scrapy that quickly, even with the proxies and user agents changing? Scrapy doesn't add anything to the request headers that gives it away, does it?

Comment: If you put pauses between your scrapes, the proxies may be unnecessary. You may be getting the error responses either from the scrape targets, because of the speed at which you are scraping, or perhaps the proxies themselves are returning these codes, for the same reason. Can you give any details about why you are using proxies and rotating your user agents? In most cases, this sort of behaviour is unethical, and without more information, it is possible that your scrape targets are right to block you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the primary problem was not having cookies enabled. Having enabled cookies, I'm having more success now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some sites incorporate javascript code that needs to be run. 
Scrapy doesn't execute javascript code so the web app really quickly knows it's a bot.

http://scraping.pro/javascript-protected-content-scrape/

Try using selenium for those sites that return 403. If crawling with selenium works, you can assume that problem is in javascript.
I think crunchbase.com uses such protection against scraping.

Answer (score 1):

For me cookies were already enabled.
What fixed it was using another user agent, one that is common.

Replace in settings.py file of your project `USER_AGENT` with this:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
```

Comment: Life saving! Was sitting late to tackle this. Previously I was using selenium to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I simply set `AutoThrottle_ENABLED` to `True` and my script was able to run.